# Expand Classic Azure VM Data disk space beyond 1023GB

Tags: azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

how do we expand the Azure VM VHD above 1023 GB. Portal is not allowing. any possibility via Script. this is classic VM

Comment: I don't think it's possible. In order to work around the size limitation, you may consider creating multiple data disks and then strip them into one partition on OS.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible:

> We are excited to announce an increase of maximum disk sizes for both Premium and Standard storage. This extends the maximum size of the disks from 1,024 GB to 4,095 GB and enables customers to add 4x more disk storage capacity per VM. Customers can now provision up to a total of 256 TB disks storage on a GS5 VM using 64 disks with 4 TB capacity. As a result, customers no longer need to scale up to multiple VMs or stripe multiple disks to provision larger disk capacity.

More information can be found on this [Blog post](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-introduces-new-disks-sizes-up-to-4tb/).